# Model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I got the following example from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true,
    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
end
```

but it doesn't work

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#index
undefined method `validates' for #<Class:0x7f1fd7b6d750>
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you running? `rails -v`

Comment: yes, it was 2.xx version, i am solve my problem with symlink to rails v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a version issue.  Installing Rails 3 solved the problem.