# "undefined method ` validates'" error - RoR Tut 5.11 Adding Some Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails noob here taking the Getting Started tutorial on RoR.org. I'm at section "5.11 Adding Some Validation", and am thrown an error when trying to refresh the /posts/new page:

The error message:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#new
undefined method `  validates' for #<Class:0x0000000414fab0>

Extracted source (around line #2):
1 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
2     validates :title, presence: true,
3                       length: { minimum: 5 }
4 end
```

**my post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**my posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all 
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

**Sidenote -** FWIW, when trying to diagnose this, I removed `@post = Post.new` from `posts_controller.rb`, and when refreshing, got this error:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

    <h1>New Post</h1>
    <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
```

Couldn't find anything wrong with the new.html.erb part of the equation, so I'm turning to the community for guidance. Anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Model validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282301/model-validation)

Answer (score 25):

After literally banging my head against the table for 30 minutes, and recreate the app three times because I thought I might've made some typo, this is what the problem is:

NoMethodError (undefined method **`  validates'** for #)

Notice that big gap between the **first quote** and **validates**? -->  **`  validates'**

Yeah, that's it. When you copy and paste the code from the site, whatever that @#$%^&* character came with it. I've copied plenty other codes from the same tutorial as well, and it all worked great.

**So the fix is to replace the invisible characters before "validates" with a space or a tab.**

Great way to "Getting Started with Rails". Just Great™. Rails, must be great™.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to all of us who lazily copy/paste. I was guilty of the same thing. Carry on my friends!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `validate` (without `s`) instead of `validates`. See [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/chapter_7_validates_vs_validate):

> The problem you're running into is probably related to my mysterious
>   and mistaken deployment of the Rails 3 tutorial. The `validates` method
>   is specific to Rails 3. Try refreshing your browser to see the correct
>   Rails 2.3 version and I think things will work better. Sorry for the
>   confusion.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Just got back home and removed the 's' from validates, refreshed /posts/new, and was thrown the same error (diff class number though) which makes leads me to believe that u/Rich-Peck is correct in saying your instructions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To contradict Uri Agassi's answer, the [Rails docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) mention this is the correct way to validate in Rails 4 (which you say you're using):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

To me, this would suggest removing `presence: true`, but I think your posted code looks like it has the correct sytanx

---

**Controller**

Another cause could be your controller:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

If you're using Rails 4, you should use the [Strong Params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) coding convention to create the record:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

If you make those 2 changes, please come back and let us know how it works

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I changed `@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))` to `@post = Post.new(post_params)` and refreshed, Rails server threw a different error in reference to index.html.erb on line #9:

_NoMethodError in Welcome#index

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
          
       <th>Text</th>
     </tr>
    
     <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= post.title %></td>
         <td><%= post.text %></td>_

Comment: Meant to add that I removed `presence: true`, refreshed and got an `undefined method validates` error.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem, removed the space as suggested and changed the method from 'validates' to 'validate', yet the error persisted. the solution I found was to make the class inherit from application record as such:`'< ApplicationRecord'`:

```
class User< ApplicationRecord
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, presence: true#, uniqueness: true
end
```

NB: this is an addition that might be useful to a newbie like myself.